# How to properly set an image and a text in the action bar?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm trying to set user's image and name in the action bar like so:

[image]

I'm not using a toolbar. The code:

```
if (receiverImageURL == null || receiverImageURL.trim().isEmpty()) {
    final Bitmap circleLetterTile = tileProvider.getCircularLetterTile(receiverFullName);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), circleLetterTile));
    setTitle(" " +StringUtils.capitalizeFully(receiverFullName));
} else {
    Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(receiverImageURL).into(new CustomViewTarget<ImageView, Bitmap>(???????) {

        @Override
        protected void onResourceCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFailed(@Nullable Drawable errorDrawable) {
            final Bitmap circleLetterTile = tileProvider.getCircularLetterTile(receiverFullName);
            getSupportActionBar().setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), circleLetterTile));
            setTitle(" " +StringUtils.capitalizeFully(receiverFullName));
        }

        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
            final Bitmap circleAvatarBitmap = tileProvider.getCircularImage(resource);
            getSupportActionBar().setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), circleAvatarBitmap));
            setTitle(" " +StringUtils.capitalizeFully(receiverFullName));
        }
    });
}
```

Which works if the user does not have an image (first `if` statement). But I have the following questions:

1. When using Glide, I need to pass the ImageView id into the `?????` place but I'm not sure how to get.
2. I really don't like the space that I used in the `setTitle(" " +StringUtils.capitalizeFully(receiverFullName));` for mocking the margin (took from other similar topic).

What would be easiest way to fix those two issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an `ActionBar` you can use:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.xxxx);
```

[image]

With a `Toolbar`:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.xxxxx);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

[image]